# comparing a cell that contains text in one sheet to a column of text in another sheet

Tags: google-sheets

There is a sheet by the name of **Inventory_Details**.
This sheet contains the material names in b5:b105.
Some quantities in the same sheet in column C correspond to each material in column b.
now,
There is a second sheet by the name of **Wellfit_site**. In this sheet, distributed material quantity, is entered which must be deducted from Inventory_Details.
In **Column C** material description given will be entered.
In the same sheet in Column D, quantity will be entered.
Text in Column C will be compared to the material names list in **Inventory_Details** sheet from cell b5 till b105.
if a match is found for the material entered in Column C in **Wellfit_site** sheet, the quantity in **Column D** will be deducted from the quantity in Column C in **Inventory_Details**.

Now the problem is I can't compare text values from the Wellfit_site sheet to the Inventory_details sheet. And unless comparison occurs, mathematical calculations cant happen.

I'll explain by example.

[image]

**Nakheel Mall**

[image]

**Wellfit**

[image]

There are 16 sites to which materials will be delivered. More will be added later. All of these will be participate in calculations. Here, I am using only 2.
I am trying to create a formula in **Inventory Details** sheet in column H **Quantity after Distribution** that will...

1. Check the Wellfit sheet in the Material Description and see which materials are there and in how much quantity.
2. Then it will look for the same exact material in the list in Column C. If a match is found, it will deduct the quantity from its corresponding Total Quantity in Column G.
3. This formula will also check Nakheel_Mall sheet so that if the same material is there, it will sum up all of those quantities and deduct it from the Total Quantity column.

I am attaching the file.

[Inventory_Managment Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11nPlatosp48mA7sTm1fZz8n9Ea2eV_Y9N_ZkYQWuDiI/edit?usp=sharing)

Help will be deeply appreciated.

I have tried vlookup function.
I have tried match and iferror function together but to no avail.

Comment: you have not attached any file.

Comment: I've fixed the link problem. You can check it again Please.

Comment: Please define your input and desired output -- their data type, format, positional relations etc. Sharing a realistic sheet to illustrate these requirements is indeed good -- editable would be even better. Still, the question should be understandable by itself; as well, the example should not include unnecessary information. For example, the tab names in the question do not match the linked example. Please give your question a review. Consult guide on [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as needed.

Comment: I've clarify the problem in more detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=map(C5:C105,D5:D105,lambda(Σ,Λ,if(Σ="",,Λ-reduce(,tocol(M:M,1),lambda(a,c,a+ifna(vlookup(Σ,indirect(c&"!C:E"),3,)))))))
```

- *the tabs which all needs to be searched can be added/updated in Column_M(as in screenshot)*

[image]

Comment: I added a new tab and put some entries.
But the formula is giving #REF error for old and new tabs both.
Maybe you can give me a new approach to how should I prepare my Inventory Details 
A more simple one.

Comment: the formula placed in`Cell_H5` is ***array-style*** & it auto-populates the numbers from H5 to H105. you dragging down the formula is what causing the #REF error.

Comment: some of the cells in Inventory Details are not updating. Some of them are exactly at it has to be.
H6 and H30 for example. They are not showing the true result.
Can you please take a look.